# Controlling Which Physical Drive DNF Update Writes New Grub Entries To

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, grub, dnf

**Background**

After a catastrophic failure of a development machine, I recently relocated the still-functional SDD with a full (including Grub) Fedora install to another machine.  This other machine still has its original SDD with a full Ubuntu install with its own copy of Grub.  The drive to boot from is selected at early boot via the motherboard firmware.  From there, I can use the copy of Grub resident on the selected drive to boot the kernel of my choosing from that specific drive.  The previous hardware is not going to be replaced so I am working to get these two installs cohabitating in perpetuity.

**Problem**

I performed a dnf update on my Fedora install which pulled in a new kernel, thus necessitating the generation of a new Grub entry.  Unfortunately, the automated installation script picked the wrong drive to install the new menu entry to:

```
...
  Running scriptlet: kernel-core-6.5.5-200.fc38.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                559/559 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (22.04) on /dev/nvme0n1p2
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
...
```

This is going to cause problems as soon as I reboot.

**Question**

1. How can I configure Grub (or DNF; whichever would be appropriate) to automatically install new bootloader entries into the correct drive moving forward?
2. To fix my current sitation, I can manually generate a new Grub entry with Grubby ([link](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/grub-menu-management#the-grubby-command-line-tool)).  Is it better to fix the immediate breakage in this way (manually) or is it safer/easier/more robust to try to correct this via package (re)installation?